# Exception "working tree already exists" while cloning GIT repo in pre-push hook

Tags: git, clone, githooks, git-push

I try to clone my local git repository inside the pre-push script (client hook). I get the exception:

```
fatal: working tree '...' already exists.
```

I don't understand the exception, since i obviously clone the repo to a different directory.

Any ideas?

---

I tried that:

```
unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
git clone ./TestTest/ /tmp/PrePushTestClone
```

It fails exactly the same way :(

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, except I was dealing with `pre-commit` hook. When trying to `clone` another repo inside the current repository there's an error with text something like:

> fatal: working tree '.' already exists.

To fix this issue I had to add this line before `clone`:

```
unset GIT_WORK_TREE
```

I have found this solution here: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1033

Comment: completely different problem but this environment variable was overriding -C and a specific path.

Comment: Worked for me. For Windows users, the command is: **set GIT_WORK_TREE=** (nothing after the =)

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me too. I realized that I ran `git clone` in a bash session opened from `git rebase -i` that had GIT_DIR and GIT_WORK_TREE set in the environment.
Exiting the bash session resolved the issue...

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I was opening a terminal from within git gui in my case (by a tool command) with all Git specific env vars set for that repository.

Answer (score 1):

> since i obviously clone the repo to a different directory.

Your hook might consider `$GIT_DIR` as referencing your current repo, which will interfere with a `git clone`.

Make sure to:

- `unset GIT_DIR` in your pre-push script
- `git clone` in a folder *outside* your current repo folder

Comment: I added the lines of my pre-push-script. It still doesent work like this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user1879408 Does `/tmp/PrePushTestClone` already exist? Ideally, it should not exists.