# Windows git bash: git clone https://github.com/... results with fatal: working tree ... already exists

Tags: git, git-bash, git-clone, git-gui

So I'm trying to clone a repo from here

https://github.com/nglglhtr/getter-setter

I created a new folder FirstDapp and opened git gui here then opened git bash from there

[image]

then I entered:

```
git clone https://github.com/nglglhtr/getter-setter
```

then the bash terminal said:
fatal: working tree 'D/.../FirstDapp' already exists

so I tried the solutions from here:

[Exception "working tree already exists" while cloning GIT repo in pre-push hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224729/exception-working-tree-already-exists-while-cloning-git-repo-in-pre-push-hook)

but those didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you run:

```
git gui
```

the GUI will search for an existing Git repository in Git's usual fashion:

- Is there a repository here, in the current working directory?

  - If so, that's it, and stop.
  - If not, try "climbing up one level", e.g., from `/path/to/current/dir`, remove the `/dir` part leaving `/path/to/current`, and start over.

If this runs out of places to look, `git gui` opens a smaller, different-looking window and offers you a chance to clone or create a repository.

(There are step I'm omitting on purpose here to simplify things, in that Git won't keep going after certain points, and under certain conditions, but these generally won't apply to your case.)

Since you did:

```
mkdir FirstDapp
cd FirstDapp
```

(or the Windows equivalent) and *did not* run a subsequent:

```
git init
```

there must not be a Git repository at the `FirstDapp` level, but Git-GUI found one, so there must *be* a Git repository at a higher level.  This is the repository that Git-GUI opened.

To get around that problem, you should create—with `git init` or `git clone`—a repository within the `FirstDapp` directory:

```
git clone https://github.com/nglglhtr/getter-setter
```

for instance.  Then running `git gui` will find *that* repository.  If you create an empty one, you'll need to do all the remaining steps that `git clone` would do, so it will be easier to use `git clone`.

(As an aside, Git-GUI is not generally recommended.  It's a bit of a toy example, rather than a real GUI.  I personally dislike GUIs in the first place and will avoid them whenever I can, and recommend that you do the same, but tastes differ.)