# fatal error working tree already exists on git bash

Tags: git

Trying to clone from a forked project to my personal system and git bash gives me the error.

```
me : $git clone https...
git: fatal: working tree 'C:/.' already exists
```

Tried many things like creating a new folder and initializing git there and here is what I got

```
git: Reinitializing existing git repository in 'C:/.(same old directory)'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224729/exception-working-tree-already-exists-while-cloning-git-repo-in-pre-push-hook

Comment: referring to the question pointed at by @Martin : what do you see if your run `echo $GIT_DIR` an `echo $GIT_WORK_TREE` in your `git-bash` session ?

Comment: Thanks, was able to sort it out by opening git bash in the new directory